# call and print the return of php script through jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem that I have a javascript code that contains stuff that I want to appear dynamicly on my html page.
And the part of dynamic content needs to be obtained from the php script, so I've heard taht I have to use j query or ajax to call the php file inside the javascript, get what it echos and then display the echoed thing using the j query/ajax/javascript to a webpage.
This is what I'm trying to do, just for an example.

**Php file (contained in helloworld.php):**

```
    <?php
    Echo "hello world";
    ?>
```

**html:**

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="credits.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**Js (credits.js):**

```
  Document.writeln("The example message for today is:"+
    "<script language='javascript'>"+
    "$.post('helloworld.php', { var1: "blah" }, function(data) {"+
    "$('#div_content').html(data);"+
    "});"+
    "</script>");
```

And I'm really getting frustrated cuz whatever I try to make the js call the php page and just display the damn contents from the echo, it just doesn't work...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using document.write?

Comment: please don't use `document.write`. In particular, there is no reason to `document.write` an inline script instesd of executing that code directly.

Comment: You need a <div id="div_content"></div> in your HTML

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for answers and suggestions, but none of them didn't work.

Comment: About the document.write, I'm using it to output stuff, and in j query, I am using because I am just not sure. I'm new to j query, and don't know what I'm doing, so if anyone could tell me what should I do to make this j query script work that would be nice. It doesn't need to be done how I've tried to do it, just so it prints the echoed string from the php on to html page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all people that have responded earlyer, but as I've already said, the suggestions didn't help to make the thing work. So I had to use php instead of js and jquery. It would be still nice if someone could tell me what way to go next time if I find myself in a trap that I have to use js/jquery.